# Nothing saved in database and no errors, many to many relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, code-first

Have a many to many relationship between users and posts. I want to create new values in the post table and the association table with postID and logged in user's ID. No error message and it looks like I can create a post when I run the application but nothing is saved in any table. I can see when I run debug it goes all the steps, even save to the database. What's wrong?

Post model

```
public class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            this.ApplicationUser = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }

        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

IdentityModels

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

       public ApplicationUser()
       {
           this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
       }

       public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

And my create function to create a new post

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Message,MessageDate")] Post post)
    {
        var manager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = manager.FindById(userId);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(post);
    }
```

I have values in all the variables for the user (manager, userId, user) and three tables (Posts, AspNetUsers and ApplicationUserPost)

**Update**

Error when I try Attach (and solution from CodeNotFound).

> Error 1   'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet'
>   does not contain a definition for 'FindById' and no extension method
>   'FindById' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   'FreePost.Models.ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Attach' and no extension method 'Attach' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'FreePost.Models.ApplicationDbContext' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The first error message is the reason I chose to use userManager.

Comment: I edited my answer then. You must use `db.Users.Attatch` instead of `db.Attach`. And `db.Users.Find` instead of `db.Users.FindById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because your `db.SaveChanges` does nothing. Your context does nothing because it know nothing about the `Post` instance you're attempting to add.

To fix that you need to first attach the current instance of `ApplicationUser` to the context like below:

```
var manager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = manager.FindById(userId);

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Line below you tell your DbContext to take care of ApplicationUser instance. 
    db.Users.Attach(user); 
    user.Posts.Add(post);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Side notes:** I will refactor your code like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Move your code that query the database here so you query your database only if the model is valid.
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    // You don't need ApplicationUserManager instance to get the ApplicationUser  instance. 
    // If your Post class have a UserId foreign key property then this line is uselesss.
    // Just set the UserId property of Post class.
    var user = db.Users.Find(userId);
    user.Posts.Add(post);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I get two error messages when I try this. I have updated my first post (too long for a comment).

Comment: @Xtreme I edited my answer then. You must use `db.Users.Attatch` instead of `db.Attach`. And `db.Users.Find` instead of `db.Users.FindById`